# Can't get sidebar to expand to parent container

Tags: html, css, css-float

As illustrated in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/He3UY/) fiddle, i can't get the `customer-sidebar` the one in yellow on the left to expand to the height of the div on the right. I have the `main-content` div on the right and it has some shipments, these shipments could vary and hence i want the sidebar to expand to the same height otherwise they will be of uneven length. I tried the "clear fix" solution but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Can someone give me a pointer as to why it's not working and how to fix it ?

Comment: When you say "width" you really mean "height", right?

Comment: Yes thirty, typo on my end, i edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create an image 1 pixel high and 1000px wide [the width of your "page wrapper"] spanning across both the side bar and the active shipment and set the image as a background within the page wrapper this is called the faux column technique.

You can take a screen shot of the page and use a snipping tool to get the image you need.

Comment: Can you explain why i need to do this, and why i can't do this without the use of an image ?

Comment: you don't really "need" to do it this way - its one method and the easiest method in my opinion of achieving what you want. As longs as the widths in your css are fixed.

Comment: Can I ask if your main-content div will always be bigger than the side bar? If that is the case then set the background colour of page wrapper that same colour as the sidebar

Comment: yes, good article explaining this technique here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/ - you can also use [js](http://www.impressivewebs.com/equal-height-columns-with-javascript-full-version/), and you could use CSS tables as in the first section of this: http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/four-methods-to-create-equal-height-columns/

Comment: Changing the back ground of the page wrapper would mean you would have to remove the black border you have created on the side bar if you use an image it would eliminate the problem

Answer (score 1):

You should place them one in another, and place the longest one in the shortest one.

If the customer-sidebar is bound to be the shortest, place the main-content sidebar inside it.

The structure should be :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="shorter-box-with-yellow-bg">
        <div id="container-box-for-shorter-list"> //floats left
        </div>
        <div id="longer-box-with-blue-bg"> //floats right
             <div id="container-box-for-longer-list">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry this answer is a little confusing, can you make a fiddle illustrating this ?